# Implement a 2-dim array using a row-major 1-dim array

Tags: java, arrays, class, multidimensional-array, implementation

Implementing a 2-dim array using a *row-major* 1-dim array
I got till here, I do not understand how I can finish the code to implement the 2-dim array, Please Help!

```
public class TwoDimArray {
int[] a = null;
public TwoDimArray(int r, int c){}
public int get(int i, int j) {}
public int[] getRow(int i) {}
public int[] getCol(int j) {}
}
```

Comment: give a sample array input and your desired output

Comment: For example if we want the two dimensional array to be 4 rows x 5 columns, we enter the data 0,0 0,1 0,2 0,3 0,4 1,0 1,1 1,2 1,3 1,4 2,0 2,1 2,2 2,3 2,4 3,0 3,1 3,2 3,3 3,4, the 2d array should display the numbers 0,0 0,1 0,2 0,3 0,4 in first row, 1,0 1,1 1,2 1,3 1,4 in second row, and so on. @Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what row-major means, but I'll assume it means that the elements are positioned in the 1-dim array by row (i.e. the first `c` elements form the first row, the next `c` elements form the second row, etc...).

1. The constructor is simple - you create an array of `r*c` elements.
2. Getting the (i,j) element is a matter of math - find a formula that given a row index `i` and a column index `j`, calculates the location in the array of the (i,j) element. Hint - the formula involves multiplying the request row by the column length.
3. Getting a row array is straight forward, since the elements of the 1-dim array that represent a single row at contiguous. As I mentioned before, the first `c` elements are the first row, etc...
4. Getting a column array involves finding the (i,j) element for each i (when j is constant).

Comment: When a 2-D array is laid out as a 1-D array of elements, row-major means that the first row of elements appears first in the 1-D array, followed by the second row, then the third row, etc.  Column-major means that the first *column* of the 2-D array appears first in the 1-D array, then the second column, and so on.  Fortran lays out its multi-dimensional arrays using column-major ordering.  Look up [Row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) in Wikipedia.

Comment: @ajb Thanks! In that case, my assumption was correct.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework, so I'm not going to give you a complete answer, but here are some thoughts that will hopefully get you started:

If you want to represent a 5x7 array (5 rows, 7 columns), you'll need to create a one-dimensional array with 35 elements (35 = 5 * 7).

The first 7 elements of `a` will be row 0; thus

- `get(0,0)` will access `a[0]`
- `get(0,1)` will access `a[1]`
- `get(0,2)` will access `a[2]`

and so on.

The 7 elements for the first row will be followed by 7 elements for the next row, and then 7 for the row after that; this means that

- `get(0,0)` will access `a[0]`
- `get(1,0)` will access `a[7]`
- `get(2,0)` will access `a[14]`

and so on.  I think you should be able to figure out the pattern and therefore get a good idea of how to make this work.

Comment: It's not actually homework, it's a practice question from the text book, unfortunately there are no similar examples making it difficult to solve. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

addition to Eran & ajb answers, this how you can get the row (i) and column (j) of the matrix

```
Columns = number of columns 
for (int i=0; i < oneDimension.length; i++)
        {
            int rowIndex = i / Columns;
            int columnIndex = i % Columns;
        }
```